# Tool for Cannonade Carbon Si Crankset

Tags: road

Used a 3/8" hex key to remove the crank but the outer bolt needs to be tightened separately. Perhaps it's possible to tighten it with the crank off or do I need a special pin type tool. Its a ~2008 Cannondale Synapse Carbon. Hollow shaft running to the opposite crank arm.

[image]

Comment: You may be able to use a [two-pin adjustable BB tool](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=two-pin+adjustable+BB+tool). That search pulls up a lot of images of the tool I'm thinking of, and they're available right down to $5 or so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be able to use a [two-pin adjustable BB tool](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=two-pin%20adjustable%20BB%20tool). That search pulls up a lot of images of the tool I'm thinking of, and they're available right down to $5 or so

[image]

(from my comment since we haven't got a better answer)